# Count the number of actions type for user before a particular action on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have table with the log of the actions made by an user, the action types are create, confirm and cancel, something like this:

```
action   datetime              user
create   2019-01-01 10:00:00   A
create   2019-01-05 10:00:00   A
confirm  2019-01-07 10:00:00   A
create   2019-01-07 10:00:00   A
cancel   2019-01-08 10:00:00   A
create   2019-01-09 10:00:00   A
create   2019-01-03 10:00:00   B
cancel   2019-01-08 10:00:00   B
create   2019-01-12 10:00:00   B
```

So, i would like to get the number of actions by type that where made by an user before each action create, so for the data before the result would be like this,

```
action   datetime              user  create  confirm  cancel
create   2019-01-01 10:00:00   A     0       0        0
create   2019-01-05 10:00:00   A     1       0        0
create   2019-01-07 10:00:00   A     2       1        0
create   2019-01-09 10:00:00   A     3       1        1
create   2019-01-03 10:00:00   B     0       0        0
create   2019-01-12 10:00:00   B     1       0        1
```

i been trying to adjust the solution for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770680/count-number-of-events-before-and-after-a-particular-event-in-sql), but cant get the different counts by action type.

```
SELECT * FROM 
  ( select *, count(1) OVER(PARTITION BY action, user ORDER BY datetime ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) create from `table` ) 
  WHERE action = 'create' ORDER BY datetime LIMIT 20;
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE: finally got 2 querys,

Query 1:

```
select *
from (select t.*,  
             countif(action = 'create') over (PARTITION BY user order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_create,
             countif(action = 'confirm') over (PARTITION BY user order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_confirm,
             countif(action = 'cancel') over (PARTITION BY user order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_cancel
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'create' order by datetime;
```

Query 2:

```
select *
from (select t.*, 
             countif(action = 'create') over (PARTITION BY user order by datetime_diff(datetime(datetime), datetime('2000-01-01'), SECOND) range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_create,
             countif(action = 'confirm') over (PARTITION BY user order by datetime_diff(datetime(datetime), datetime('2000-01-01'), SECOND) range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_confirm,
             countif(action = 'cancel') over (PARTITION BY user order by datetime_diff(datetime(datetime), datetime('2000-01-01'), SECOND) range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_cancel
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'create' order by datetime;
```

When the user has more than 1 action at the same time, the Query 1 works better. Thanks!!

UPDATE 2: Final query

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT action, datetime, user, 
    COUNTIF(action = 'create') OVER(win) `create`,
    COUNTIF(action = 'confirm') OVER(win) confirm,
    COUNTIF(action = 'cancel') OVER(win) cancel
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY user 
    ORDER BY datetime, CASE action WHEN 'create' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) 
)
WHERE action = 'create'
ORDER BY user, datetime
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want cumulative sums and filtering:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             countif(action = 'create') over (order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_create,
             countif(action = 'confirm') over (order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_confirm,
             countif(action = 'cancel') over (order by datetime rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_cancel
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'create';
```

Actually, your times have duplicate values, which can be a bit tricky.  I would recommend that you change the problem to include the current time frame.  But if you really need "before", you can use `range`.  Unfortunately, `interval` is not allowed, so you have to convert the ordering criterion to a number:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             countif(action = 'create') over (order by datetime_diff(second, datetime('2000-01-01'), datetime) range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_create,
             countif(action = 'confirm') over (order by datetime_diff(second, datetime('2000-01-01'), datetime) range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_confirm,
             countif(action = 'cancel') over (order by datetime_diff(second, datetime('2000-01-01'), datetime) range between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as num_cancel
      from t
     ) t
where action = 'create';
```

Comment: Thanks!, ive made a few changes to the query in order to get the actions by user, but as you said, the duplicated times are tricky, sometimes it doesnt count the action, because happended at the same time, can i add some kind of position order? i look at row_number, but i dont know how to pass that value to the seconds so it affect the the order inside the over.

Comment: @AlvaroFlores . . . The second query with `range` partitioning addresses this issue.

Comment: yes, thanks, tryed both and the first one was better when the actions had the same datetime and user.

Comment: @AlvaroFlores . . . Mikhail's answer is the same as my first query, but posted many, many hours later.  I'm curious why you accepted that answer.

Comment: btw. I don't see them as same  - they are quite different!! and actually even producing different result. so I think your answer is wrong, but it is up to OP to judge :o) which looks like he did and re-accepted your answer now. which I think is quite misleading :o)

Comment: thanks you both, im sorry for the confusion, i thought both answers where made by the same person.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant . . . I see that they are different.  I missed the conditional partitioning.  You are right.  The OP should choose the version that works.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - thank you for checking and confirming :o) I noticed that in bigquery tag voting activity is very weak so OPs do not have that extra factor that would helped them to identify best answer. it is - what it is :o(

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT action, datetime, user, 
    COUNTIF(action = 'create') OVER(win) `create`,
    COUNTIF(action = 'confirm') OVER(win) confirm,
    COUNTIF(action = 'cancel') OVER(win) cancel
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WINDOW win AS (
    PARTITION BY user 
    ORDER BY datetime, CASE action WHEN 'create' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  ) 
)
WHERE action = 'create'
ORDER BY user, datetime
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row action  datetime                user    create  confirm cancel   
1   create  2019-01-01T10:00:00     A       0       0       0    
2   create  2019-01-05T10:00:00     A       1       0       0    
3   create  2019-01-07T10:00:00     A       2       1       0    
4   create  2019-01-09T10:00:00     A       3       1       1    
5   create  2019-01-03T10:00:00     B       0       0       0    
6   create  2019-01-12T10:00:00     B       1       0       1
```

Note: "issue" with duplicate dates is resolved here by using `CASE action WHEN 'create' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` in the order by clause of window expression.

Comment: have you tried this solution? looks like you missed it! :o)